# Is there way to join two tables in SQL not on you index row without getting rid of null values

Tags: sql, presto

I have two tables in SQL that look similar to the following:

```
Code        Symbol       Value
1203        ABC          10.00
1208        XYZ          12.00
1222        null         9.00
1226        ABC          1.00
```

and

```
Symbol       Date
ABC          2020-06-07
XYZ          2020-06-08
QRS          2020-06-10
```

Currently, I am trying to join them as follows

```
SELECT a.Code, a.Symbol, a.Value, b.Date
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.Symbol = b.Symbol
```

This returns the following output:

```
Code        Symbol       Value          Date
1203        ABC          10.00          2020-06-07
1208        XYZ          12.00          2020-06-08
1226        ABC          1.00           2020-06-07
```

However, I would like to still keep all rows from the initial table as such and fill in the missing values as null as such:

```
Code        Symbol       Value          Date
1203        ABC          10.00          2020-06-07
1208        XYZ          12.00          2020-06-08
1222        null         9.00           null
1226        ABC          1.00           2020-06-07
```

I know this is likely quite straightforward but I have tried researching it and I think I am having a brain cramp because I can't work my issue correctly to find what I need.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does presto support coalesce? Like select a.code, coalesce(a.symbol, 'na') as symbol, coalesce(a.value, 'na') as value, coalesce(b.date, 'na') as bdate from table1 a left join table2 b on a.symbol = b.symbol

Comment: It does support it

Comment: @RyanReid . . . Your query should be doing what you want.  My guess is that you have the tables reversed in your actual query.

Comment: I only have postgres to work with, and your query works just fine for me. I'm not familiar with presto. I agree with GL, where maybe the tables are reversed in the query.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: I agree with @Gordon Linoff, you probably have your tables in reverse order. Either flip the tables, or use a `RIGHT JOIN` instead.*

Sounds like you want a `LEFT (OUTER) JOIN`. For a general overiew, see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

```sql
WITH a AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1203, 'ABC', 10.00),
                 (1208, 'XYZ', 12.00),
                 (1222, null, 9.00),
                 (1226, 'ABC', 1.00)
         ) as a (code, symbol, value)
), b AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ('ABC', '2020-06-07'::date),
                 ('XYZ', '2020-06-08'::date),
                 ('QRS', '2020-06-10'::date)
         ) as b (symbol, date)
)
SELECT code, a.symbol, value, date
FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.symbol = b.symbol
```

```
+----+------+-----+----------+
|code|symbol|value|date      |
+----+------+-----+----------+
|1203|ABC   |10   |2020-06-07|
|1208|XYZ   |12   |2020-06-08|
|1222|NULL  |9    |NULL      |
|1226|ABC   |1    |2020-06-07|
+----+------+-----+----------+
```

Comment: What if there is a symbol in table1 that does not occur in table2 but I would like it to be in the left join?

Comment: As it describes in the documentation, if a row is present in A without a counterpart in B, you can show it using a LEFT JOIN. If the row is present in B without being in A, use a RIGHT JOIN. If you want both, use a FULL JOIN. Hope that helps